# PayUMoney: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, payumoney

I am trying to implement PayUMoney Gateway in my application, I have used sample app for this. i have followed all the steps and generate the Hash Key from server for a live(Production Environment), I have followed http://achieveee.com/payu_documentation/custom-ui-android/ for generate Hash Key but i am facing exception, So kindly help to solve it.

My Hash Key response looks like below

```
{
    "message": "successfully generated hash",
    "save_user_card_hash": "d10c017102332c1ef52c19e1893698089c645c3f6a57f9bb7947bea4af736539688dc11e8f807e59a2b2a5e6783de16daaf51eb305b964f88f35110c1a911625",
    "payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash": "50d32847c16d2167eb2cad38017c0a858d472f08b441f65a9641c82919ea9b7723d3f6c4ac2937ca0a9318218877ff1fb351e9d7bd5e242c5cf7ef147e802855",
    "get_merchant_ibibo_codes_hash": "b06a11db98172a6ff3d775dede3494b08c94ed2148cd71e56936bd42e305c3ff0d76fa61ada30948f458f8d942ab6c761c1aae8362c113bf24645c060dd854af",
    "get_user_cards_hash": "5489ab2717414767e0b807f098c4f2b7cbb3c5926384dcc98889a4b4952392f5b69b8c653f8bd62cc08d506c2ded724957c5356f6d2ec14e4174e9e3a732c6e4",
    "vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash": "4ecd2a5d31e001a4f345defea8decd829b43bad78ea606ad081335a3a8c4eb28aad5a62fcca59a2c17a275227f07eff43955b3ea6b399d8ff186f53f5fdf289c",
    "edit_user_card_hash": "3b629ae6eb7lkuydb46028655c9947d988b65e3436f7dddcd9beec070e84f883839aa03797d74b8b6088e7c1be54cd664598c1137ac8d707d9f7c0f53442ccfe",
    "payment_hash": "05035d428e0c7e045351adc6b97d1ba8776c17dcedd50f341749e21967mnt0b07b766b8b21a07756298d3a9ec1333a7456db39213c356714cd212ea79cd9047c",
    "send_sms_hash": "b2e73e276a96a4cf98e43103dba8146c64a8e3c31ba1bbb04f8a3390dd3460c4177zsed12e9f71b54c3eab90131606523bb4394e442d268601bf4c473c0a63c2",
    "delete_user_card_hash": "fec11d3e8d936d80362c5fb05e109c673ae69730f8e3df5958e77d56a6belye6bc7826d516fc6a7824d65d53863b521c50fb78b676784cb6900a01064b8c2e82",
    "verify_payment_hash": "3bcb617fceae9aa401ba4810d6adf1169d7347bf544ea3d4c369182f0da765721f98axdew7284762094586ba47b0b1fe085cd4b31c9368404c5f90587ea3f5f"
}
```

My exception log looks like below

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at com.payu.india.Tasks.ValueAddedServiceTask.doInBackground(ValueAddedServiceTask.java:105)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at com.payu.india.Tasks.ValueAddedServiceTask.doInBackground(ValueAddedServiceTask.java:52)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
com.payu.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: on success check what string your are getting

Comment: What is your response contains ?

Comment: You getting HTML Data instead JSON so can you please check your response.

Comment: I just entered amount,Email and clicked on pay now at that time it is showing exception . The Hash Key is generated but next it's showing exception i don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: Yet  I didn't succeed!

Comment: Show your response

Comment: I am not getting any response, i am getting exception which i have already mentioned above.

Comment: Have you done this  `JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseStringBuffer.toString()); ?`

Comment: Yeah I have done this in GetHashesFromServerTask using Asynch and I'm getting number of Hash Keys like

"save_user_card_hash"
"payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash"
"get_merchant_ibibo_codes_hash"
"get_user_cards_hash"
"vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash"
"edit_user_card_hash"
"payment_hash"
"send_sms_hash"
"delete_user_card_hash"
"verify_payment_hash"

Comment: Print this `response` and `responseStringBuffer.toString()` in `Log`.

Comment: I have updated response.

Comment: Ok. So now when you iterate this response getting error at that time ?

Comment: No I am getting exception when redirect to the next screen PayUBaseActivity.java

Comment: Is it your class or third party class ? And is there any web service calling or json data iterating ?

Comment: Yeah third party class which in SDK
https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/blob/master/sdkui/src/main/java/com/payu/payuui/Activity/PayUBaseActivity.java

Comment: The problem is in **setupViewPagerAdapter** method in PayUBaseActivity class. There is in if condition  **payuResponse.getResponseStatus().getCode()** is not matched, The code is 5014 instead of 0.

Comment: There is reported same issue and remain open issue :(.  https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/issues/21

Comment: yes ...i am also facing the same.....issue...any solution???

Comment: Any solutions yet?